# Autofilter using Date in UK Format

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()
    Dim s_date As Date
    Dim lo_j As ListObject

    Set lo_j = mytable.ListObjects(1)

    s_date = ThisWorkbook.Names("in_date").RefersToRange(1, 1)

    Debug.Print s_date

    With lo_j.Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=s_date
    End With
End sub
```

In the above code `s_date` prints in VBA immediate window as "31/12/2018".

However, when its applied to the filtered table it is shown as "12/31/2018". This causes the autofilter to show nothing.

I have tried to convert the s_date to a string but this doesn't solve the problem. How do I force `s_date` to be applied as "31/12/2018" in the autofilter table?

Furthermore all data in column 10 of the table are dates.

Comment: Try converting it to a number: `Criteria1:=CLng(s_date)`

Comment: If you work with dates make sure you **always** work with real dates and not with strings that look like dates. Strings that look like dates are extremely evil because eg for a string like `"01/12/2018"` neither a computer nor a human can tell if it is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`. • Therefore I recommend only to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format `yyyy-mm-dd` which is the only one that cannot be misunderstood.

Comment: CLng(s_date) doesn't work. I get a number in the filter: 43465 which obviously doesn't match any data

Comment: What works, is to change the date format of the cells in column 10 to Locale United States and Type: 3/14/2012. Not ideal solution though as it is very unsafe

Comment: I am thinking of creating a separate column and use the ISO 8601 format as suggested by Peh

Comment: @JoannaMikalai note that Excel saves real dates as numbers like `43465` no matter what is shown in the cell. This number is the amount of days since `1900-01-01`. So if you save a **real** date into a cell then Excel actually just saves a number that represents the amount of days and formats it what ever you choose as numberformat.

Comment: Yes I agree, but if you try and autofilter dates using a number '43465' (applied from VBA) it won't work. I believe, autofilter is based on the numberformat you choose for the cells...

Comment: I forgot you need to use 2 criteria, like this: `.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(s_date), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(s_date)`

Comment: Hi Rory, ok this makes sense now, and it works fine. thank you

Comment: Using `Format` should also work as long as it matches your cell format: `.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Format$(s_date, "dd/mm/yyyy")`